# Don't have access to view objects permissions

Tags: windows, file-permissions, permissions

Last week I provisioned a new Windows 2008 R2 box from my hosting company and copied my databases files to the file system. It became necessary to reimage the OS on the box so they left the database files on the local drive and reimaged the box. Now that the image is complete I’ve logged back into the box and tried to reattach the database files but I received an ‘Access Denied’ error. On 8 of the 10 files I was able to add the Administrator account to the file and complete the attachment but on 2 files the Security tab is blank except for the message “You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.”

Can anybody tell me how I can access the permission settings for the 2 rouge files?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user is the sql server running as? ... does that user have full permissions?  (check services manager and look at the "Log On As" user.)

Comment: SQL is running as LocalSystem. I don't think SQL is the problem. The problem is that I can't change the permissions on the actual database file. I was able to change 8 out of 10 but there are 2 of which I'm locked out.

Comment: Take ownership of the file... then adjust permissions as you see fit.

Comment: That did it. Thx.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem now.  What does "Take ownership of the file" mean?  How do you do that?  @Chris?

Comment: NM, found explanation [here](http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/you_do_not_have_permission_to_view_or_edit_this_object_permissio/?TopicId=58182&Posts=0)